# How to install application Updates on multiple windows machine using any tool or script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-installer, devops

I have around 100  windows machine(VMs), All the machines have few updates for chrome , notepad/notepad++ , Firefox  ,Jenkins which have not been installed from long time, Is there a way to install updates in all the machines without going to each application specifically and updating.

can we log into each machine and execute any command so that all the update for applications is installed?

Basically want to trigger auto-update in all the windows machines.

Comment: Could you please tell what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put a lot of effort, but it's doable.

You need to know how to update each application via command line. And when you have all the commands. And you can do updates on single Windows instance. You can use Enter-PSsession or Invoke-Command (for HyperV guest) / Invoke-VMScript (for ESX guest)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct

https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/invoke-vmscript/#Default